# Need easier way to replace nested custom tags with HTML equivalents

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to properly replace nested custom tags with their HTML equivalents.  For example, suppose we have the following text:

```
This is {b:bold text}
```

Which should become:

```
This is <b>bold text</b>
```

I'm aware that I can - and probably should - use something like a span with a "bold" class instead of the old "b" tags, but there's a reason I'm sticking with "b" for the purpose of this example.  I may have nested tags:

```
This is {b:bold text and {i:italic}}
```

which should become:

```
This is <b>bold text and <i>italic</i></b>
```

However, I have these regexes (which I use with the replace() function):

```
/\{b:([\s\S]*?)\}/gm
/\{i:([\s\S]*?)\}/gm
```

And then the result will become:

```
This is <b>bold text and <i>italic</b></i>
```

The tags are not properly nested.  Again, using spans can solve this in this case, but that won't work with things like "ul", "li", "h1", ...
Greedy regexes will also cause problems if the text looks like this:

```
This is {b:bold text} and {i:italic}
```

So my current solution is to replace everything with span first, using a data-tag attribute to indicate what it should actually be, and then use jQuery to find all span nodes and replace them with the proper tags:

```
{h:This is a header}
becomes
<span data-tag='h1'>This is a header</span>
becomes
<h1>This is a header</h1>
```

It works well, but i'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this.  The intermediate  method feels a bit like a duct tape solution and I would like to "beautify" it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Parsing" languages with a variable "tag-depth" via regex is not 100% possible. Better use a real parser. -- I tried this a while ago with BBCode.

Comment: It's not clear if you are looking to create your own templating/markup system, or if you are trying to parse existing data. You may want to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I'm trying to build my own templating system.  Partially because then I can have it behave exactly the way I want to, and partially because writing stuff like this instead of using existing templating engines seems like an excellent way to learn new JavaScript tricks and even revisit some of the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the Regex and use one of the many templating tools out there, such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), or [t.js](https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js).

**EDIT:** *Fixed!*

...but if you are avoiding such simplicities in life, here's how to do it with a regular expression:

```
var rex = /\{(b|i):([^{}]*)\}/igm,
    parse = function(txt) {
        var cnt = 0,
            more = true;
        while (more) {
            txt = txt.replace(rex, function(match, $1, $2) {
                return "<" + $1 + ">" + $2 + "</" + $1 + ">";
            });
            more = rex.test(txt);
            cnt++;
        }
        return txt;
    };
```

So you call `parse` and pass it your string. It recursively parses your string until no other mark-up is found. This new one works in reverse, parsing out the items that *don't* have items within, then moving outward.

To implement the H1 example that you added, you could either instead us `{h1:This is the header}` and add it to the `(b|i)` clause, or use a `switch` statement in the replace function instead of just returning $1.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc5GR/3/).

Comment: jQuery templates are still in Beta and judging by the tags used for this question OP is probably not interested in jQuery just plain JavaScript.

Comment: A downvote? A little harsh don't you think. Despite being in beta, jQuery templating is quite stable - and he didn't say anything about not wanting to use templates.

Comment: sometimes people are not allowed to use third party codes or have specifics requisites.

Comment: @Grinn This is still more a post of commentary kind and not a real answer. I didn't vote down, but I think it's understandable.

Comment: Downvote was from me...jQuery templates are "no longer being actively developed or maintained" (top of the page that you linked to). It's not clear if the OP is parsing some existing custom code or building a template system from scratch. This answer would be a better comment.

Comment: @Grinn I also didn't vote down but I also don't think this answer the question

Comment: @Grinn The downvote you received wasn't mine because I don't make use of them.

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior: Again, OP didn't say that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize jQuery Templates were being dropped. I took it out.

Comment: Removed my downvote since you updated your answer; hopefully you will update it further if it turns out the OP isn't seeking a templating system.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I updated my comment to include a way to do it with Regex.

Comment: Doesn't work for `This is {b:bold text {i:italic test}{b:bold text}}`,

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  I put some more info in a comment below the original post.  The idea is to build my own templating system, both to have a system that works exactly the way I want it, and as a learning experience.

Comment: @WebStakker: Yeah, I just noticed that. I'll keep banging on it.

Comment: @WebStakker: I updated my answer. Hopefully I got it right this time ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late answer on my part.  It took some time to test everything and get back here.  Both solutions offered help me out, but I like yours best.  It is more concise, and it requires no traversing each character of the text (which might become problematic when content gets longer).  Thanks both for your help.  Just wanted to pop in and close this topic.

Comment: No worries. 'Tis the season for putting work off! Thanks for making it back here and up-voting.

Answer (score 1):

A simple stack goes a long way

```
function doReplace( str ) {
    var stack = [],
        ret = [],
        ch;
    for( var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; ++i ) {
        var ch = str.charAt(i);

        if( ch === "{" ) {
            var pos = str.indexOf( ":", i+1);
            if( pos < 0 ) {
                throw new SyntaxError();
            }
            var tagName = str.substring( i + 1, pos);
            if( /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(tagName)) {
                throw new SyntaxError();
            }
            ret.push( "<" + tagName + ">" );
            stack.push( tagName);
            i+= tagName.length + 1;
        }
        else if( ch === "}" ) {
            if( !stack.length ) {
                throw new SyntaxError();
            }
            var tagName = stack.pop();
            ret.push( "</" + tagName + ">" );
        }
        else {
            ret.push( ch );
        }
    }

    if( stack.length ) {
        throw new SyntaxError();
    }

    return ret.join("");
}

doReplace( "This is {b:bold text {i:italic text{i:italic text{i:italic text{i:italic text{i:italic text{i:italic text}}}}}}}")
//"This is <b>bold text <i>italic text<i>italic text<i>italic text<i>italic text<i>italic text<i>italic text</i></i></i></i></i></i></b>"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go and let you know how it works out.

Comment: @WebStakker let me know if there is a bug :-)

Comment: Nice, however I think you should output the braces as they are when encountering nesting or tag name issues, instead of throwing syntax errors.

Comment: @Bergi Yes but it's easier to debug for now, when the error handling is very strict. A cool addition would be keeping track of line and column, and then output exactly where and what error happened.